# What does "Voice Command" "Unexpected server error occurred. Please try again." mean?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, voice-command, system-error

When I restart my Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100), I get an error message:

> Voice Command
>
> An unexpected server error occurred. Please try again.
>
> [OK]

This started ever since I download the trial version of (redacted) earlier tonight, but its still happening even after I uninstalled it.

I've not accepted the Voice Command agreement. Whenever I accidentally activate it by pressing the home key the wrong way, I select `Decline`.

What does this error message actually mean?

Comment: **Hello!** If you've arrived here from Google because you have the same problem, please *don't* post "Me too!" or things of that nature. Simply bookmark this page or click on the star icon to the left to mark this question as a [favorite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), then check back periodically for updates and answers.

Comment: I dont think this issue is related to any download it just happen to me too , with out changing any config

Comment: PRISM was being deployed

Comment: I've removed the name of the software I had coincidentally downloaded. I'm now seeing lots of people posting similar questions in other forums and they can't all have downloaded the same app.

Comment: This question has got nearly 40k views in just two days. I can't remember if this has ever happened before on Android Enthusiasts. [I would also guess that it is a server issue.](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/47460/440)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting this error constantly today, so I went to `Settings` → `Applications` → `All` → `Voice Command`. From there I clicked `Force Stop` → `OK` then `Clear Data` → `OK`. Then I relaunched the voice command by tapping the microphone button on my Google search widget.

The Voice Command worked perfectly, and I haven't seen the error message in about an hour.

Comment: That seems to do the trick for me too. I'll post here again if it comes back. Many thanks.

Comment: I followed these steps (force stopped and cleared data) and when I reopened it with double click middle button, same error message straight away before I get a chance to accept the license terms.

Comment: Did not work. Samsung GS2, Sprint.

Answer (score 6):

For now, you can disable voice commands from `Settings->Applications`. I am sure it is a Samsung server issue.

Answer (score 1):

[On this forum](http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130617193907AAynvxv&cp=3) someone mentioned the following:

> I just called samsung technical support. Google voice has a problem with their server in the mean time you can disable voice command under settings - applications - All - voice command click that then click disable. Was told the message will stop popping up. Tech # 1800-762-7864

I did notice the same problem on my SGS2 yesterday but I haven't seen any error messages since yesterday evening so I suspect the issue has been resolved by either Samsung or Google.